# IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate bad rendering on Linux Mint 19 Cinnamon

Tags: intellij-idea, linux-mint

I just installed **IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2018** on my laptop (Linux Mint Cinnamon 19) and I realized it had really bad visual quality compared to my other laptop running Linux Mint Cinnamon 18. I also downloaded the 2017 version and I got the same result. In the pictures bellow you can see the no colored buttons, odd font representation and weird looking progress bar.

[image]

[image]

[image]

The picture bellow is taken for comparison from my other laptop running Linux Mint Cinnamon 18 and IntelliJ Ultimate 2017.

[image]

Can I fix this somehow?

Comment: I was going to suggest the version of QT.  But a quick internet search says I am wrong and it uses Swing.  I guess maybe that is true.  What version of Java are you using?  (Also check the QT version because I thought sure I was right).  Edit: but IntelliJ comes with its own JVM.  Weird.  Maybe you don't have the fonts it wants installed in X?

Comment: I went back to Linux Mint Cinnamon 18.2, and IntelliJ IDEA 2018 Ultimate looks great, so I guess my computer wasn't the problem. Maybe the graphic card drivers?

Comment: Are/were there any errors in [log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085)?